# Produce Discrete fourier transform of multiple time series within one csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv with multiple time series and although I can create all DFTs in a single plot. I want to separate out all the plots.[DFT of all time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz44q.png)

I created the DFT of all time series as a single plot overlapped on each other. The code I am trying is this-

```py
    uni_1 = []
    for item in time_series:
      if item not in uni_1:
        
        uni_1.append(item)
    
    for u in uni_1[0:50]:
    
    small_df= df[df["time_series"]==u]
    
    # convert into x and y
      
    
          x = list(range(len(small_df.index)))
          y = (small_df.Quantity).tolist()
    
    # apply fast fourier transform and take absolute values
        f=abs(np.fft.fft(y))
    
    # get the list of frequencies
        num=np.size(x)
        freq = [i / num for i in list(range(num))]
    
    # get the list of spectrums
    spectrum = f.real*f.real+f.imag*f.imag
    nspectrum = spectrum/spectrum[0]
# plot nspectrum per frequency, with a semilog scale on nspectrum
    plt.semilogy(freq,nspectrum)
```

I want to separate out the plots for better visibility.

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: I just added the code I am trying

Comment: Post code as text, not links or images.

Comment: posted code as text

Comment: Indentation is not there just to make things "pretty". In your case, depending on what the actual indentation should be, it changes what your program is supposed to do. So, please, double check your indentation. As it is, your code is not runnable. But, if the indentation problem is just a Stackoverflow copy/pasting problem, then you could try adding a plt.figure() before the plt.semilogy(...) and a plt.show() right after it. plt.figure() creates a new figure, plt.plot(...) creates a plot and plt.show() actually draws it.